# How can I get the cluster IP info within the Kubernetes yaml file before it's been created?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a docker container that needs to run in Kubernetes, but within its parameters, there's one need the container's Cluster IP info. How can I write a Kubernetes yaml file with that info?

```
# I want docker to run like this
docker run ... --wsrep-node-address=<ClusterIP>

# xxx.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: galera01
  labels:
    name: galera01
  namespace: cloudstack
spec:
  containers:
  - name: galeranode01
    image: erkules/galera:basic
    args:
    # Is there any variable that I can use to represent the
    # POD IP or CLUSTER IP here?
    - --wsrep-node-address=<ClusterIP>
```

Comment: we can't define the IP address for the POD.  you can create the service first and add pod label to match the service selector label. you use service IP to access your pod.

Comment: @sfgroups I think I could use the hostname(which could be resolved by Kubernetes DNS server) to replace the <ClusterIP> here, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

If i get this right you want to know node ip for which runs the container.

You can achive this by using kubernetes dns.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

> Services 
>   A records
>   “Normal” (not headless)
>  Services are assigned a DNS A record for a name of the form **my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local**. This resolves to the cluster IP of the Service.

Another way you can create a service and use this.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#accessing-the-service